# How do I add PC BSD / FreeBSD to Grub 2 boot loader?

Tags: boot, freebsd, dual-boot, grub2

I have Ubuntu 10.04 installed as my primary operating system, and I installed PC BSD in a different partition: `/dev/sda4` without installing it's boot loader. I figured out that I need to edit `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` to add an entry for PC-BSD. So far, nothing seems to work, though.

EDIT: this sort of works, but doesn't fully boot the OS, it then asks me for the MOUNTROOT partition.

```
menuentry "PC-BSD 8.1" {
    insmod ufs2
    set root=(hd0,4)
    kfreebsd /boot/kernel/kernel
}
```

The selected answer below is correct. If you are dual-booting with Linux I suggest *NOT* installing the PC-BSD bootloader as the documentation suggests, unless you enjoy pain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is what I have in `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`. Works for me :) Just remember to subsitude `hd0,3` with your correct entry

```
menuentry 'FreeBSD 8.0 64bit' --class os {
    set root='(hd0,3)'
    chainloader +1
}
```

Comment: I think that for this to work you need to have the PC-BSD boot loader installed into the PC-BSD partition boot blocks.  I sounds like postfuturist does not have the PC-BSD boot loader installed anywhere.
If the PC-BSD boot loader can live in the PC-BSD partition boot blocks installing it there will probably get postfuturist up and running.

Comment: In the graphical installer there is a button at the bottom of the disk selection screen titled "Install PC-BSD boot loader": http://wiki.pcbsd.org/index.php/PC-BSD_Users_Handbook#Disk_Selection_Screen . Does this just install the boot loader on the partition, or the MBR of the disk?

Comment: @postfuturist: I don't know, but you can try installing it and restore `grub` if it is installed on the MBR. Here is the guide for restoring grub https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Grub2#Recover%20Grub%202%20via%20LiveCD

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution mentioned here: [Add FreeBSD to GRUB2 boot menu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109278/155643), which is:

```
menuentry "FreeBSD" --class freebsd --class bsd --class os {
 insmod ufs2
 insmod bsd
 set root=(hd0,1)
 kfreebsd /boot/kernel/kernel
 kfreebsd_loadenv /boot/device.hints
 set kFreeBSD.vfs.root.mountfrom=ufs:/dev/ada0s1a
 set kFreeBSD.vfs.root.mountfrom.options=rw
 set kFreeBSD.hw.psm.synaptics_support=1
}
```

This solution worked for me triple-booting Ubuntu 12.04, LFS 7.9 and FreeBSD 10.3