# Add FreeBSD to GRUB2 boot menu

Tags: freebsd, grub2

I have Gentoo x64 installed with Grub2 on my MBR drive. Today I installed FreeBSD x64 9.2.
Now I'm in Gentoo and trying to add FreeBSD to `grub2` menu list.

```
grub2-install /dev/sda
os-prober
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

I did the above on Gentoo and it didn't find FreeBSD. The FreeBSD nested partition is on `sda1` and contains `freebsd-ufs` and `freebsd-swap` partitions.

How could I add FreeBSD to `grub2`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is mine:

```
menuentry "FreeBSD" --class freebsd --class bsd --class os {
 insmod ufs2
 insmod bsd
 set root=(hd0,1)
 kfreebsd /boot/kernel/kernel
 kfreebsd_loadenv /boot/device.hints
 set kFreeBSD.vfs.root.mountfrom=ufs:/dev/ada0s1a
 set kFreeBSD.vfs.root.mountfrom.options=rw
 set kFreeBSD.hw.psm.synaptics_support=1
}
```

Comment: did you generate it with os-prober or you did it yourself. **also** which file did that directive go in?

Comment: does the sda1 translate to `hd0,1` ? is it true that grub2 start from 1 not 0?

Comment: No, this /isn't auto-generated. I've wrote it into /etc/grub.d/40_custom, check this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Automatically_generating_using_.2Fetc.2Fgrub.d.2F40_custom_and_grub-mkconfig

Comment: Yes, (hd0,1) is sda1.

Comment: the freebsd is in the /dev/sda1 but the sda1 is a partition slice (according to bsd terminology); and it contains a `/` and `swap` partition. How should I precede then?

Comment: I did paste your directive to the 40_custom and then ran `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`. but nothing added to grub menu at the boot time!!!

Comment: Also **I installed freebsd not kfreebsd**. I mean not the debain release of freebsd.

Comment: I'm using freebsd too. Check this page: http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Multi_002dboot-manual-config.html#Multi_002dboot-manual-config

Did you 'chmod +x' to 40_custom? Please-please check http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/GRUB2#ISO_images


In my case the config above works well. Did you try?

Comment: It didn't work with me.
What almost worked with me was chainloader (hd0,gpt11)/boot/loader.efi
on <code>40_custom</code>. but the efi firmware dont start the kernel
I going to continue the search

Answer (score 3):

My Goal was to: Boot FreeBSD 10 from Grub2 by editing 40_custom in /etc/grub.d

My Setup: FreeBSD10 is on the fifth hdd of my system (/dev/sde under Linux, so hd4 for Grub2. Remember that under Grub2 hd starts from hd0 for drives, and partitions from 1 and on, not zero). The root partition is the second one (/dev/sde2) as I've used FreeBSD's Guided partitioning (use entire disk) while installing (simplest).
Recalling, that is: set root='(hd4,2)' for the fifth hdd and the 2nd partition.

info: (chainloader +1 is actually not required ! The following brings me directly to FreeBSDs Bootloader).

To summarize a little: you just got to adapt set root=(x,x), nothing more is needed. If you want to boot the kernel directly, things get a little more complex than the entry below.

```
menuentry "FreeBSD 10.0" {
    insmod part_gpt
    set root='(hd4,2)'
    kfreebsd /boot/loader
}
```

I was a bit disappointed by os-prober which just found 'Unknown linux distribution on /dev/sde2'

ps: don't forget 'update-grub' afterwards and Taddaa (hopefully). :) If somebody succeed, throw me a msg, i would be happy to hear from you !

Comment: good for gpt partition table

Comment: What is `insmod part_gpt` ?

Comment: `insmod` - module loader. `part_gpt` - provides support for GPT (GUID Partition Table) partitions and partitioning tables. Not sure this line is necessary.

Comment: `kfreebsd` only works when the `bsd` Grub module is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

#### Do it in this order:

1. Edit your `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` and *[add uzsolt's directives](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109278/128489)*. Add the directive at the **end** of the file. **Don't delete anything that is in there**.
2. Make sure `40_custom` is executable. If not then `chmod u+x 40_custom`.
3. Now do this to write the changes to `grub.cfg`.

   ```
   grub2-install /dev/sda 
   os-prober 
   grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
   ```
4. Tada! Reboot now; you should have FreeBSD in your OS list in GRUB menu.

#### To have access to your UFS partition slice you should do the following:

1. Edit your kernel configuration to add `UFS filesystem` and `UFS label`.
2. Then `make && make_modules` your kernel.
3. Install the **UFS filesystem software**.
4. Mount your UFS Slice under your Linux:

   ```
   sudo mkdir /mnt/freebsd && sudo mount -r -t ufs -o ufstype=ufs2 /dev/sda1 /mnt/freebsd
   ```

Comment: Both `os-prober` and `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` show that there is an `unknown Linux distribution on /dev/sda16`. Now FreeBSD is not Linux and I followed these steps exactly

Answer (score 1):

According to [this site](https://srobb.net/grub2.html):

1. Boot Linux.
2. Create a `/boot/grub2/custom.cfg` file.
3. Add these lines to the created file:

   ```
   menuentry "FreeBSD" {
   set root='(hd0,3)'
   kfreebsd /boot/loader
   }
   ```

   where `hd0,3` means this is the first hard drive and FreeBSD is on its third partition (since disks are numbered from 0 and partitions are numbered from 1). Probably you'll have to adjust those numbers. One way to find out what your disks are is to run `fdisk -l`.
4. Run `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`.

Remember that your commands might be slightly different. `grub2-mkconfig` might be `grub-mkconfig` and so on (this was my case on BunsenLabs Linux).

---

Mind that I was using FreeBSD with UFS instead of ZFS on this machine. The presented solution does not work for ZFS-based installations from what I've heard.

Answer (score 0):

The [Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#FreeBSD_menu_entry) has a very nice explanation for the same. It guides the normal way i.e. direct OS loading as well as chainloading.

However, one must not forget to issue `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` to commit changes.

Answer (score 0):

Currently on Ubuntu 20.04 and FreeBSD 12.x below thing works.

/etc/grub.d/40_custom file in Ubuntu, add the following:-

```
root@a44h-ubuntu:/home/xxxxxxx# more /etc/grub.d/40_custom
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
menuentry "FreeBSD" {
        insmod ufs2   
        chainloader (hd0,msdos1)/boot/boot 
        #does not work for me
        #set root=(hd0,1)     #does not work for me
        #kfreebsd /boot/boot0 #does not work for me
        #chainloader +1       #does not work for me
}
```

Then turn on the boot manager menu at boot up, change :-

```
#GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="hidden"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="menu"
```

then do:

```
root@a44h-ubuntu:/home/xxxxxxx# update-grub
```

Nothing needs to be done in FreeBSD.

The `hd0` is first hard disk and `msdos1` is `s1`.

Answer (score 0):

the config for my particular setup the setup (using UEFI and GBT) in /etc/grub.d/40_custom is

```
menuentry "FreeBSD" {
        insmod ufs2   
        chainloader (hd0,7)/boot/loader.efi 
}
```

for your setup you might need to modify the following:
hd0 might need to be changed if you have multiple disks,
the "7" is the partition number(if using MBR then add msdos before the number such as "msdos7"),and
if you are using BIOS change "loader.efi" to "loader"(I have not tested this).
I am not sure what to do if you are not on ufs