# How to dual boot PC-BSD 10.3 (with zfs file system) and debian 7 (crunchbang) using grub2 boot loader in MBR?

Tags: debian, freebsd, grub2, mbr

I want to dual boot PC-BSD 10.3 with ZFS as the root file system (the only file system) with Debian 7  (crunchbang linux) with ext4 using grub2 boot loader installed in MBR and grub is managed by the debian.

All the documents are dealing with dual booting PC-BSD/FreeBSD using UFS2 file system and Debian([How do I add PC BSD / FreeBSD to Grub 2 boot loader?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/859/how-do-i-add-pc-bsd-freebsd-to-grub-2-boot-loader)). So I'm asking the question here.

From my debian's grub configuration

```
cat /etc/grub.d/40_custom 
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
menuentry "PC-BSD" {
insmod zfs
set root=(hd0,2)
chainloader +1
}
```

This entry is being detected by the grub and showing in the boot screen. But when I select PC-BSD, it is showing the error "UFS not found". I think this is because PC-BSD 10.3 is using ZFS instead of UFS2. Please provide me the guide to boot PC-BSD with ZFS and debian using grub2 managed by debian.

Comment: This has been solved by following the steps in this link http://www.thegeekylinux.com/2014/11/how-to-dual-boot-linux-crunchbang-linux.html Yes, I had to use PC-BSD grub to dual boot Linux and PC-BSD

Comment: You version of PC-BSD must be wrong. It can't be 10.3, because  that's not available. Just now, 10 months after your question was PC-BSD10.2 released.

Answer (score 2):

Use PC-BSD GRUB. It's the only one GRUB that can boot FreeBSD/BCBSD from zfs. Debian GRUB doesn't support the zfs currently used in BSD.